# html and css display my menu selection

Tags: c#, html, css, multiple-select

I want to write an HTML page that will contain several things:

1. a banner on the top of the page
2. a box that inside there will be types of food with multiple selection, for example:

   - eggs
   - tomato
   - pasta
   - carrot
   - toast
   - cucumber

...the user can select more than one type of food...

3. under the menu box there will be Time table that will include all days in a week

...and in this table the user will see all the types of food that were selected from the upper box.  I want to add the selection box but I have a few problems.. I don't want to use the `<select>` tag. Also, how can I "save" the user selection in order to display the selected items in the time table?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: you need to show us your code so we can try to help you. Is that C#  ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! a good question needs the codes you are tried. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unfortunately we tend not to do your homework for you. If you can show us what *you* have tried, we will always try our best to help, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your design and html done, you need to use java script in order to allow user to select item form list (that can be a checkbox). You can save selected value as a JS var and append / display on your page in table if that's your plan ?
You should create a jsfiddle with your code and show us where are you stack